# How to reference two users(each with a different role) in an Entity Framework Class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I have one entity that relates to two users in the AspNetUsers table:

1. User with the role of Tenant
2. User with the role of Landlord
3. Property (Created with entity framework)

I can't figure out how to relate 1 tenant and 1 landlord with 1 property when creating foreign key relationships in my property context. To do this I would need to implement two foreign keys in my property class but they would both be a UserID from Identity. That doesn't seem right though and I can't get my head around it. Below is what the beginning of my Property.cs file would look like.

```
public class Property
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string PropertyID { get; set; }
    [Key, ForeignKey("User")]
    public string LandlordId { get;set; }
    [Key, ForeignKey("User")]
    public string TenantId { get;set; }

    //other fields

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get;set; }
}
```

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Just made some edits. Hope they make the question clearer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways to do this:

1. Keep your current model, and ensure you set up the navigational properties correctly:

   ```
   public class Property
   {
       public int PropertyId { get; set; }
       public int TenantId { get; set; }
       public int LandlordId { get; set; }

       public User Tenant { get; set; }
       public User Landlord { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   Notice that, since this correctly follows convention over configuration, there's no need for applying `[ForeingKey]`.
2. This is going to represent a bigger change in your application. You would need to introduce a `Landlord` and a `Tenant` entity:

   ```
   public class Landlord
   {
       ...
       public int UserId { get; set; }
       public User User { get; set }
   }

   public class Tenant
   {
       ...
       public int UserId { get; set; }
       public User User { get; set }
   }
   ```

   And then map those to the `Property` entity:

   ```
   public class Property
   {
       public int PropertyId { get; set; }
       public int TenantId { get; set; }
       public int LandlordId { get; set; }

       public Tenant Tenant { get; set; }
       public Landlord Landlord { get; set; }
   }
   ```

Now, which of those approaches make more sense in your business domain and in this application is up to you to decide.

Comment: Will "public User Tenant { get; set; }" get the userid of a user in my AspNetUsers table that have the role name of "Tenant" in my AspNetRoles table?

Comment: Not automatically, no. In both cases you'll need to code that logic manually

Comment: That's what I'm struggling to figure out... I originally created a landlord and tenant entity but read that it was best practice to differentiate users with roles and claims. Thank you anyway though!

Comment: @Luke There's no best practice there, it depends entirely on your business. It's easier to see if `Landord` is another entity though